# Http Error 403: Forbidden with exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, github-api

Im trying to scrap the data from github api I have almost 1500 such links
[Example link](https://api.github.com/users/eviljeff)

I am getting HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Any body give me any idea how can I handle it with exception handling in python?

here is sample Code

```
for link in author_url:
        if link=="None found":
            continue
        link = Request(link,headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}) 
        response = urlopen(link) 
        raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8") 
        author_data = json.loads(raw_json)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know the proper way of handling it without knowing which packages you are using for that Request object and openurl method. I'm assuming you are using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html#module-urllib).

I would put a try/except around the `urlopen(link)` to catch any errors that occur in the request.

Something like this would work for urllib:

```
for link in author_url:
        if link=="None found":
            continue
        link = Request(link,headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'})
    try:
        response = urlopen(link) 
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 403:
            # Handle error here
    raw_json = response.read().decode("utf-8") 
    author_data = json.loads(raw_json)
```

Comment: You might need to import HTTPError from the urllib package if you are using that. Ex: `from urllib import HTTPError`

Comment: It is actually `from urllib.error import HTTPError`